# Format HtmlEncoded text to ASP

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, html

I am taking string from database, which will then be HtmlEncoded. How do I do the formatting of newline and tab?

I don't think I will be able to use CSS because it is only one string (unless using CSS to replace the substring)

One way I've tried is by putting `<br>` and  `&emsp;` inside of the text in database and then using HttpUtility.HtmlDecode to format it, but I am not sure it is the right way.

Any suggestion and feedback is welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting a html encoded string from database then you just have to use htmldecode for decoding and it will place tabs and new line.
Prior to that check if the encoded string is html encoded or any other encoding has been used.